# ASP.NET Web Service validating incoming XML

Tags: asp.net, xml, web-services

I have ASP.NET 4 Web Service (asmx). I use IXmlSerializable interface for manually serialization/deserialization. In the function ReadXml (part of IXmlSerializable) I use functin XmlReader.ReadString and if client send me invalidate XML this function throw exception. How I validate incoming XMl before deserialization? Because exception is very hard operation for perfomance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put the deserializatin in a try catch block and handle exception in catch. there is no point in validating xml upfront as it might through an exception when you attempt to validate as well.